# Send a file through email after Paypal payment is recieved

Tags: php, paypal

Is there any way to send a file in an email upon receiving a Paypal payment? Any tutorials to show how to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are using HTML Form based processing, when Paypal payment is successful you will get the response in IPN script. You can use phpmailer or some other PHP email class to attach a file and send an email

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sending email is easy using the built in [mail](http://php.net/mail) function in PHP. However, sending attachment is a whole other story.

I'd use a third party library like [phpMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

E.g. sending email with attachment:

```
require_once('path/to/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! Have you used this with Paypal? My php is terrible but they have a tutorial on there site explaining about the IPN so will this code work with Paypal too? The site I'm working on is a photography site that will be selling there Photo's online so will this work for many different Photo's or will I have to copy the same code for each photo?

Comment: This answer looks like it can send a email, nothing else.

It does not meet the condition when payment via paypal is received.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [SwiftMailer / attahching files](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#attaching-files) if I were you upon receiving confirmation from PayPal.